# Calcular Valores em espaços não preenchidos no Form

Tags: c#, string, conversão-de-tipo, textbox, conversão

Boa tarde!

Estou com duvidas na hora de implementar um algoritmo que possa calcular o fluxo de calor baseando-se nas fórmulas:

**q=ΔT/Rt

ΔT=Temperaturainicial-TemperaturaFinal

Rt(resistência Térmica)=L(Espessura)/K(contutividade)*A(área -m²)**

Todas possuem textbox e gostaria de criar uma condição lógica que se um campo não preenchido o programa informe no textbox o calculo realizado. Segue um exemplo que fiz mas não rodou a segunda condição.

```
//calcula q=ΔT/Rt


if (txt_Resist.Text.Trim() != null && delta_temp.Text.Trim() != null)
        {
            decimal q;
            q = Fluxo_Calor(Convert.ToDecimal(delta_temp.Text.ToString()), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Resist.Text.ToString()));

                 //informa o valor de q no textbox do resultado

                     txtResultado.Text = q.ToString();
        }
        //Calcula Q=(Temperaturaincial-Temperaturafinal)/Rt
        else if (txt_Resist.Text.Trim() != null && txt_delta1.Text.Trim() != null && txt_delta2.Text.Trim() != null)
        {
            decimal delta, q;

            delta = Deltatemperatura(Convert.ToDecimal(txt_delta1.Text.ToString()), Convert.ToDecimal(txt_delta2.Text.ToString()));
            //Retorna o valor de delta no textbox
            delta_temp.Text = delta.ToString();

                            //informa o valor de q no textbox do resultado
            q = Fluxo_Calor(delta, Convert.ToDecimal(txt_Resist.Text.ToString()));
            txtResultado.Text = q.ToString();}
```

[image]

Comment: Aparentemente o erro da imagem é algum problema na conversão da string para decimal. O valor desse campo que você está tentando converter para decimal possui somente números, "." ou ","?

Comment: Poderia colocar o código da função Fluxo_Calor()

Comment: Você poderia utilizar a forma txt_Resist.Text.Trim() != null (que está errada, pois sempre será uma string vazia, não um null) pela !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txt_Resist.Text). Além disso a propriedade Text não precisa do .ToString() depois dela, pois já é uma string.